# Copying an image from a file to the clipboard using BatchFile

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, command-prompt, clipboard

I am trying to copy an image from a path into the clipboard using the command line in windows.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you've tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've made any effort to research the issue yourself before posting here. Did you try searching this site for `[batch-file] clipboard` to see if there's anything already here that might get you started?

Answer (score 1):

Launch a Powershell script to copy file to clipboard

there are plenty on the web like [Copy image to clipboard using PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/andytuba/13b9fe7ea7f3405c04d338f93b399ff8)